# VB.NET - Unable to enforce two digit day and month when converting string to Date

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, type-conversion

I am having difficulty taking a string and converting it to a vb.net Date object, while enforcing two digit day and month.  Please consider the following form example, using today's date. (02/01/2019)

```
    Dim myDate As Date = Date.Now

    Dim myDateString = String.Format("{0:D2}/{1:D2}/{2:D4}", myDate.Month, myDate.Day, myDate.Year)

    myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)

    Label1.Text = myDate 'This will show "2/1/2019"

    Label2.Text = myDateString 'This will show "02/01/2019"
```

This situation leaves Label1.Text as "2/1/2019", but Label2.Text as "02/01/2019".  No matter what I have tried, it appears that the actual conversion from the correctly formatted String into a Date object will remove these zeros.  Does anyone have any thoughts as to how I can enforce a "MM/dd/yyyy" format when converting to a Date object?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: In addition to Steve's answer, a `Date` has no format because internally it is merely represented by a single 64-bit integer, holding the number of "ticks" since 0001-01-01 (1 tick = 100 ns = 0.1 µs).

Comment: 2019-02-01 00:00 is stored as 636845760000000000.

Comment: These are the kind of bugs that are so easy to avoid when you put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file.  Now you get the red squiggles on the bad code, forcing you to write correct code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider that a DateTime variable has no format. It is just a number expressing the [Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2) elapsed from the starting DateTime.MinValue (1/1/0001).
It has no memory that you have built it using a particular formatting parser.

So, when you assign a date to a string like you do in your

```
Label1.Text = myDate
```

then you are asking the *ToString* representation of that date. The output of this method *without a formatting parameter* is whatever your locale settings decide it to be. If you want to force the desidered output you need to tell the date's *ToString* method in what format you want the output

```
Label1.Text = myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```